# Why are NSTableView and NSOutline view creating large blank spaces and columns out of order

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I am having issues with NSTableView and NSOutlineView created in Interface Builder, where once I add a certain number of columns, they start rendering very strangely at build time.

[image]

The columns sometimes appear in the wrong order, and always render with blurry text. I've tried completely removing the entire table/outline view and starting again, which works sometimes but usually results in the same thing, but not always with the same columns.

[image]

As you can see it looks like something is drawing on top of the table.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Is "at build time" during build? Is Autosave Column information switched on? Did you change the identifiers of the columns? Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project? Please post a [mre].

Comment: By "at build time" I mean when built/run, as opposed to when viewed in IB. Column Autosave is switched on... I have been changing the identifiers as I'm refactoring some stuff. You may well be onto something. Thanks.

Comment: Autosave column information was the answer. Thanks so much. I hadn't realised the impact of changing column identifiers.